# Show only an image when pin gets selected on map view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dictionary

I am trying to show an image when any pin point gets selected on MKMapView. When user taps on any pin I want to show only image without any title, subtitle, left or right CalloutAccessoryView.
Any help is appreciated.

---

[image]

I want show something like this image.
I can set image for pin but not able to show image when it's get selected.
Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{

    MKPinAnnotationView *customPinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];         
    customPinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"userLocImgae1.png"];
    return customPinView;               

    }
```

write your image name.